# Unable to add color to text

Tags: materials, text-object

I am using blender 2.66. I have added a text object and then selected the Object tab in the properties window, went up to the bottom and the used object color picker to choose a color.

But even after choosing a color, when I render the scene as image the color does not seem to be applied to the text object. Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [creating a material](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Materials/Assigning_a_material).

## Blender internal:

1. Create a material in *Properties > Materials panel*:

   [image: > Add new]
2. To simply add some color, you probably want to set the *Diffuse color* instead of the object color:

   [image: in the Diffuse panel]

Object color only affects the render when enabled in *Material > Options*:

[image: Object color]

Object color is used to add some color variance per object without adding new materials.

## Cycles:

AFAIK, *Object color* is not used at all in cycles.

### Render:

To give an object a color in the render for cycles:

1. Create a new material in the *Materials* panel by pressing *Add new*:

   [image: > Add new]

   This will automatically add a *[Diffuse shader](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Nodes/Shaders#Diffuse)*.
2. Adjust the *Color input* of the diffuse shader:

   [image]

### Viewport:

To give the object a color in the 3D view set the *Viewport color* in *Properties > Materials > Settings > Viewport color*:

[image]

Note that the *Viewport color* is separate from the colors defined in the material which will appear when rendered. (It will only affect the 3D view)