# Coloring an Ocean

Tags: materials

How do I color & texture a Plane with the Ocean Modifier?  I first create a Plane, then I 'Add Modifier' and choose 'Ocean'  I now want to make the surface look like an ocean but don't know how. I then animate the Ocean.
WFR

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/4871/599

Answer (score 24):

You must [add a *Material*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Materials/Assigning_a_material).

To add a material, press *New* in *Properties > Materials* with the ocean selected:

[image].

Note that your world/sky setup will (and should) influence the look of the ocean material a lot, since the real ocean gets it's color from the sky.

## Cycles

For a basic ocean shader in cycles you probably want to use a [glossy](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Nodes/Shaders#Glossy) or a [glass](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Nodes/Shaders#Glass) shader.

You can either use the interface in the *Properties panel*:

[image]

Or the [*Node editor*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Materials/Nodes/Editor):

[image]

For a slightly more complex ocean shader:

[image]

[image]

## Blender Internal

For a basic ocean material in BI, enable *Mirror* and tweak the *Diffuse*, *Specular*, and *Mirror* colors:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just a remark - I think it's a good idea to use the real IOR of water in this case: 1.33.

Comment: True.. I just hacked this up in a couple minuets and it completely slipped my mind :P. Though sea water can have a higher IOR (due to salinity, temperature, etc.), so 1.4 *could* actually be the IOR of a sea/ocean somewhere ;).

Comment: Where can I add the Volume Scatter and Volume Absorbtion nodes?  I'm on 2.69 and don't see those options in the Add > Shader menu.  Is this part of the Cycles volumetrics features in 2.7?

Comment: Just got 2.7... looks like those are 2.7 features!

Comment: For everyone stuck with weird looking water using this, you have to not use a plane, but a volume for this. Then it looks fabulous :)