# Filling a 3D Mesh

Tags: mesh

I currently have a mesh of a building (it has a texture). Initially it was a solid; however, I sliced off the top to remove noise in MeshLab. Now I have a mesh that's really only an outline. Any ideas how to fill it? I tried <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>, but that didn't go very well.

An alternative hack would be to have a plane of the same shape, filled with a colour, and put inside (not sure how to do this either).

Thanks! Below is a screenshot of the mesh to show you what I mean.

[image: Example]

Comment: For such a complex hole, you wont be able to fill this in one step (with useful results). First try create an ngon, then join edges across logical creases in the shape.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Depending on the topology of the mesh, you could try:

- Grid fill (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>*> Grid fill*).

  [image]
- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> to fill, then <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to try and remove unnecessary triangles.

  [image]
- Simply filling with an N-gon (<kbd>F</kbd>).

  [image]

Comment: Tried all 3. First two had poor results, with the colour coming through the mesh and texture. The last one was almost perfect, but came out like this: http://puu.sh/8AAa3/8192211433.png

Comment: @user2976601 Make sure you only have the top edge loop selected (hold `Alt` while selecting an edge with RMB to select the entire edge loop).

Comment: You sir, are a god amongst men. The ALT+F and ALT+J method worked. Had to hold SHIFT and ALT and select multiple top edges (didn't pick up the whole thing in one click) THANKS! PS. Gifs were extremely useful.

Comment: Any ideas how to change the fill colour?

Comment: @user2976601 You'll have to create another material or edit the texture/UV mapping. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/4871/599