# How to add color to objects

Tags: materials

I'm trying to make a YouTube intro and I can't find how to color the title. Where do I find colors for my project? I can't find anything on my computer that I can import. Do I need to download them? If so, from where?

Comment: Possible duplicate:  [Unable to add color to text](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/4871/2217)

Answer (score 1):

Colors are not directly assigned to objects, objects can have multiple materials which control the properties of surfaces or volumes.

[image]

With your object selected open the materials tab and click the *New* button.

[image]

The newly created material shows some properties like *Diffuse* and *Specular* color change them as you like.

The appearance of the objects depends also on your camera orientation and light sources. If it appears dark or even black try to add another lamp.

Related:

[Add different materials to different parts of a mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh)

Answer (score 1):

To expand a bit upon what Stacker suggested, in the materials context tab, if the layout doesn't match what shows in Stacker's answer, click on the word "diffuse" to open the diffuse pane, and the word "specular" to open the specular pane. When these are first opened, the default hue may be gray instead of the blueish hue in Stacker's second illustration. If this is the case, click on the gray bar (or whatever color it might be) to open a color chooser dialog box.

Also, the object can appear black if the text object is in a layer that does not have an active lamp. In this case, you might be able to make the hue of the object show the way you want by adding the visibility of a layer that already has lamps.